# Large Scale Distributed Application in AWS / Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, amazon-web-services

I am working on a large scale web app where the users can be from anywhere in the world.

Considerations:
1. Web servers needs to be distributed in possibly 3 data centers possibly across 3 continents.
2. Each datacenter might have 2 webservers (ASP.NET) to start with and can scale out
3. The database needs to be partitioned (SQL Server sherding). Not thinking of separate database instances and mirroring
4. The application will have media contents. So, a CDN might be right fit for them.

Hosting Options:
1. Azure/AWS IaaS: In this case the Web and Applciation servers needs to be configured and managed by us
2. Azure/AWS PaaS: Here we get tied up with using vendor specific tools, code blocks and "way of doing things" and finally one fine morning they announce they are retiring a dependant service (eg. SQL Azure federation). Also, to consider the limits around db max size 150GB for Az SQL and throttling within shared services.

So, Hosting Option 1 looks the safe bet around.

Now my questions:

1. I need to consider a load balancing server for each DATA Center that will route traffic to 2 or more Web Servers in that data center. But what about managing the traffic from anywhere of the world come to its desired data centers? In the IaaS model, where do I put the load balancer that distributes web traffic across datacenters?
2. I came across Azure traffic manager that seems take care of the problem 1 above, but does that work with their IaaS offering? What is the equivalent in AWS? It is desired that when an user connects from APAC, they get redirected to the DC in Asia.
3. In sherding model, we want to partition specific database tables and not all. I am not quite familiar, but how does failover work in sherded database? Can I have active passive SQL servers for each member database server in the federation? (BTW is SQL federation same as Sherding?)

The application itself is ASP.NET and SQL Server based.

Comment: There are a lot of great questions here, but I think that as it stands this question is far too broad for a specific answer.  Some of these answers will be strictly opinion based as well.  Perhaps this would be better broken down in to smaller questions.

Comment: Check out Route 53 Latency based routing (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingLatencyRRSets.html) with Health checks (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover.html), and Elastic Load Balancer (http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) with AutoScaling (http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/) in multiple AWS regions

Answer (score -1):

Max size now 1 terabyte for SQL Azure - see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/ and look at the premium tier...